# Silverlight Memory store

Tags: silverlight, memory

I'm making a silverlight website.

Is it possible to make some kind of a memory where i can store some values and can recall them from different pages?

thx

Comment: When you say "recall from different pages", do you mean other pages that will run your silverlight control, or other HTML pages? If it's all in your silverlight control, use Isolated Storage. If not, you probably want to store the data in some backend and use the RIA Services to write to it from Silverlight and read from your page.

Comment: Please clarify if you're making an ASP.NET website that has SL components embedded within it, or if you're making a 100% SL site.

Comment: I mean other pages in the same silverlight project, I think Isolated Storage is what I was looking for, I'm trying it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I normally create a class called Session, with a property called Default that looks like this:

```
public class SessionBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class
{
    public static T Default
    {
        get
        {
            var instance = Application.Current.Resources["SessionName"] as T;
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                Application.Current.Resources.Add("SessionName", instance);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

}
```

Then in my app.xaml I have:

```
<Classes:Session x:Name="SessionName"/>
```

This way you can access the same instance with binding and with c# (code behind). T inherits SessionBase and in that class you can store any information you want and it will remain available throughout the application session. eg:

```
public class Session : SessionBase<Session>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

You will then be able to bind to X (need to raise the PropertyChanged for two way binding) and access it from c#